# Directing url to html homepage instead of an .asp homepage

Tags: html, asp-classic, hosting

I am trying to upload a new site in place of an existing one. The domain name and everything is already set. The old site how ever was built using asp files, so when I upload my html files, they don't link (going to the homepage only works if the homepage is .asp instead of .html, but that means none of my other pages will go back to that because all the links are html). I am using Filezilla, too. How can I change it to look for .html instead of .asp? Hopefully this makes sense, I have not encountered .asp files until now, so I am trying to figure out how this works.

Comment: Look at the order of processing the default files. This would be found within your administrator panel.  If index.asp is higher in the list then index.html, then the .asp page will have precedence.

Comment: Last comment is correct if you just need to handle the default home page. If you need to send all pages (e.g. Contact.asp => Contact.html) this is easily done by saving a COPY of all .asp pages with .html extensions, then adding redirects to empty .asp pages, effectively redirecting any .asp links to your newly crafted .html counterparts.

Comment: @mjw: What? That's a really bad idea. edooley, follow the lead from WorkSmarter and set your default pages in the control panel.

Comment: I agree it's a bad idea. But if OP is set on using newly crafted html pages instead of simply modifying the links throughout the website to point to the correct pages, changing the default page won't be sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't have something server-based like form or input tags, then just rename the file from sth.html to sth.asp. It could work at least loading the page. If you have form tags or server-side part, then you have to edit your html code to asp grammar. Did I understand your question right?

Comment: Yeah, it would probably work if i changed everything to .asp instead of .html, was looking for a way to avoid that. I'm also working on mac, and .asp would just complicate things further because its windows only, right?

Comment: Is your new site hosted on IIS or Apache?  Classic ASP is indeed windows only, but it's server side code, so there's no reason why you can't write your code on a Mac then upload to a Windows server.

Comment: Yes and no, .asp is a server technology which runs on Windows servers, however editing .asp pages could be done using any text IDE on any platform.

Comment: @edooley I got it. Then, you have some options:
1. make server installed Windows servers (like amazon ec2), and move your asp files to that server
2. choose another server language like jsp, php, then recode it(I don't know how many files you have)
3. (It's not appopriate for programmers) save every .asp files to .html file using browser, and then reuse it.
4. (I'm not confident this could help,) search about 'jekyll', famous framework for making static website

Comment: @dev_strender - What are you talking about? Why don't you look at WorkSmarter's comment in the OP's post and use that method.

Comment: Paul, you seem to be confused. Try reading the OP's actual problem instead of assuming the default page is the only content for the website.